# MySQL group records by month does not show records as expected

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have written the following query but it does not group the records by month. Some of the records are displayed without order. I am unable to get the reason behind it.

```
SELECT   MONTHNAME(CREATE_TIME) AS MONTH
        , FEATURE AS featureName
        , count( DISTINCT(FEATURE) ) as featureCount
        , app_name as appName
FROM    ceye.approve
WHERE   create_time > now() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
 AND    review_time IS NULL
GROUP BY MONTH 
        , FEATURE
        , appName
ORDER BY MONTH desc ;
```

The data displayed by it is as follows:

| Month | Feature | SUM | App_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| October | Replace PAN Card | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| October | S3 | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| October | View Account Summary | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| November | login | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| November | Replace PAN Card | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| March | login | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| March | update profile | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| January | FI unfreeze PAN Card | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| January | login | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| January | Replace PAN Card | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| December | login | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| December | Replace PAN Card | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| December | update profile | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| December | update user profile api | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| April | login | 1 | Mobile Banking |
| April | login | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |
| April | update profile | 1 | Markets Research Portal |
| April | update profile | 1 | Retail Bank Portal |

Comment: Month names are strings, so they're sorted alphabetically, not by their order in the calendar.

Comment: @Barmar i want them by the order in calendar. How do I get that?

Comment: I already explained this in my answer. It's like you asked "how to get an egg in perfect state?" and then someone tells you the exact amount of seconds you have to cook it. This is the purpose of Stackoverflow and this is like people can help people. What you are doing here is like - to still follow my example - "this does not work, I don't know how to use my burner".

Comment: `FEATURE AS featureName, count( DISTINCT(FEATURE) )` That makes no sense. Since the `Feature` column is included the select list, the count will always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

When you would like to sort by the months according to their order in the calender, you have to order by their number. You can achieve this by using MONTH. In this way, you can get the month number for the given dates and do the sort:

```
ORDER BY MONTH(creation_time) DESC
```

Here is an example that shows it's working fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5380faabda823313ff73ef4b1932593c)

Comment: it throws this error: ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ceye.approve.create_time' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: when I add your said line to order by clause

Comment: select MONTHNAME(CREATE_TIME) AS MONTH,FEATURE as featureName,count(DISTINCT(FEATURE)) as featureCount, app_name as appName
from ceye.approve
where
        create_time >now() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
  AND
    review_time is NULL

group by MONTH,FEATURE,appName

ORDER BY MONTH(CREATE_TIME) DESC;

Comment: If i add create_time in select statement, it create a cartesian product in result

Comment: Then you should change your query. Sorry, I can't explain you entire SQL, this is quite too complex for stackoverflow. My answer just explains how to do a sort by month according by the "calender order".

Comment: `If i add create_time in select statement,` Despite the error message, you don't need to add "create_time", only `MONTH(CREATE_TIME)`. Then order by MONTH(CREATE_TIME)  as well. Also, if the data includes multiple years, you should sort by year then month number

Answer (score -1):

Research order by case as an example -

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T(DT date, val int);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('2022-01-01',10),
('2022-02-01',10),('2022-02-01',10),
('2022-03-01',10),('2022-03-01',10),('2022-03-01',10),
('2022-05-01',10),('2022-05-01',10),('2022-05-01',10),('2022-05-01',10),('2022-05-01',10);

select monthname(dt),sum(val)
from t
group by monthname(dt)
order by
case when monthname(dt) = 'December' then 1
      when monthname(dt) = 'November' then 2
      when monthname(dt) = 'October'  then 3
      when monthname(dt) = 'September' then 4
      when monthname(dt) = 'August'   then 5
      when monthname(dt) = 'July'     then 6
      when monthname(dt) = 'June'     then 7
      when monthname(dt) = 'May'      then 8
      when monthname(dt) = 'April'    then 9
      when monthname(dt) = 'March'    then 10
      when monthname(dt) = 'February' then 11
      when monthname(dt) = 'January'  then 12
end
;

+---------------+----------+
| monthname(dt) | sum(val) |
+---------------+----------+
| May           |       50 |
| March         |       30 |
| February      |       20 |
| January       |       10 |
+---------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: You could use the `FIELD()` function instead of that big `CASE` expression.

Comment: `FIELD(monthname(dt), 'December', 'November', ...)`